# Media class not found after upgrading to JDK 13 and JavaFX 13

Tags: java, javafx

I made a project when i had JDK 8 (I think?) and the default JavaFX that came with e(fx)clipse. It worked fine but recently I upgraded them to JDK 13.0.1 and JFX 13, and now it just crashes because it can't find the Media class.

The project was simple it just plays from the middle of a mp4 file and pauses the video after 1 second. Here's the code:

```
package test;


import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    public MediaPlayer mp;
    public Timeline tl;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage win) throws Exception {


        Media m=new Media(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test/videoplayback.mp4").toExternalForm());
        mp=new MediaPlayer(m);
        mp.setVolume(0.5);

        MediaView mv=new MediaView(mp);

        AnchorPane pane=new AnchorPane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(mv);

        Scene s=new Scene(pane,640,360);
        win.setScene(s);
        win.show();
        p();

    }

    public void p() {

        mp.play();
        tl=new Timeline(

            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.01),event->{
                mp.seek(mp.getStartTime().add(Duration.seconds(118.4)));


            }),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),event->mp.pause())

        );
        tl.playFromStart();
    }

}
```

And here is the error

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/media/Media
    at test.main.start(main.java:28)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.media.Media
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 10 more
Exception running application test.main
```

I have added the whole javafx libraries to the build path, Inculuding javafx.media.jar. Other common javaFX classes seem to work, but nothing under javafx.scene.media works. I made a new project, and it was just like this one. Everything works except for classes under javafx.scene.media.

I don't have enough brain cells to know where I should go from here, so please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Follow instructions at https://openjfx.io

Comment: @jewelsea I did follow them to install javafx and as i said it works it's just anything related to media that dorsn't work

Comment: When you [add modules](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx), are you adding `javafx.media`?